# HTTP request does not work when called from a class in python

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I have a class A and it has a postit() method.
Module name: test.py

```
class A():
   def postit(self, D):
     try:
       '''
       request = urllib2.Request("localhost:8079" + '/check/hello-test', D, headers)
       response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

       '''

      conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8079")
      conn.request("GET", "/check/hello-test")
      response = conn.getresponse()
      print ("Whey")   
     except:
      print("Failed to connect!" )
```

There is a server listening at the above port given. 
When I run the uncommented code inside as a python code, the script sends request to the server, but when I do `from test import A`, then call the postit function. It fails and I get the error returned.

The above postit() function is called internally for a purpose and it fails to send a request and get response. I need to know why.

I have also tried removing the 'D' argument and it still fails.

Comment: Indent your code, and include the error in your question. Unless you by error you refer to `"Failed to connect!"`. In that case i d suggest avoiding `except:` without any exceptions.

Comment: Inititalize class A and then run postit() it fails to send a request. I write a simple script and execute the same code inside postit(), it works well.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it fails? Is it printing "Failed to connect!" or some other error?

Comment: `for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: ':' should be the problem..But still not working.